# Is there a size limitation for creating an app with apache cordova ?

Tags: cordova, size

Is there a size limitation for creating an app with apache cordova ?

Since now, I tested my app with xcode, on my iphone4 and I didn't have any trouble to build an app wich contain more than 50MB of data.

so what about this link: http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/11/14/bigger-apps-have-arrived/

I thought cordova and phonegap was the same ?

will the size limitation cause me trouble only when I will pass it throught the apple store ?

Answer (score 0):

Your link refers to PhoneGap Build which is a service that enables to to create Cordova applications via the cloud - while based on the same technology, it isn't the same as installing and using Cordova locally.